# Sprockets::FileNotFound couldn't find file 'bootstrap' with type 'text/css'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, error-handling

So this is the error I am getting in my browser when I try to run the rails server:

```
          [couldn't find file 'bootstrap' with type 'text/css']
```

I have this in my gemfile:

```
          gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.5.1'
```

And this is my application.css.scss file:

```
          *= require bootstrap

          *= require_tree .

          *= require_self
          */

          @import "bootstrap";
```

Does anyone know how to get this up and running??

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem and removing

```
    *=require bootstrap
```

and adding

```
    @import "bootstrap-sprockets";
    @import "bootstrap";
```

to the end of application.css.scss file solved the problem